# Representing natural numbers as sums of distinct prime powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

I am investigating whether every natural number $n > 18$ can be represented as a sum $p_1^{m_1} + \dots + p_k^{m_k}$, where $p_1, \dots, p_k$ are distinct primes, and $m_1, \dots, m_k$ are distinct positive integers. This conjecture is based on computational observation for numbers up to 500.

Questions for the community:

1. Is there existing literature on this result or a similar topic?
2. Any suggestions on approaches for proving this conjecture?

Comment: If you want "sufficiently large" instead of "every $>18$", then you could probably fix $k=10, (m_1,\dots,m_k) = (1,2,\dots,10)$ (actually, maybe $k=2,(m_1,m_2)=(1,2)$ could already be proven to work), and then the usual circle method argument will give enough solutions to $n = p_1^{m_1}+\dots+p_k^{m_k}$ (for large enough $n$) that you can deduce there is a solution with $p_1,\dots,p_k$ distinct.

Comment: See "K. Prachar, “Über ein problem vom Waring-Goldbach’schen typ II,” Monatshefte Für Mathematik, vol. 57, no. 2, pp. 113–116, 1953" and references therein and thereof. It seems this problem was first looked at by Roth?

Comment: Also, @mathworker21: surely $k=2$ could never be achieved by pure circle method? That's at the barrier of even square-root cancellation in the exponential sum being too little to show the minor arc contribution is smaller than the major arc.

Comment: (to put it another way, if you're able to solve this, what's stopping you from solving binary Golbach?)

Comment: @AnuragSahay Yea, of course; meant to say $k=4$ I think (so that $1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4 > 2$).

Comment: Aha, fair enough! I didn't look too hard for improvements over Prachar but perhaps there has been one.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of literature on the topic; the magic words are: "Waring-Goldbach" problem.

Starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%E2%80%93Goldbach_problem

Comment: There are three differences between the Waring-Goldbach problem as described on Wikipedia and the conjecture that I stated: 1. In Waring-Goldbach the exponents are identical. 2. In Waring-Goldbach the number of summands has an upper bound. 3. My conjecture has distinctness conditions that are missing in Waring-Goldbach.

Comment: There are several possible variations. But when you are looking for a way of representing an integer with a sum of a finite number of prime powers, no matter if the exponents or the primes are the same, you have a Waring-Goldbach problem.

Comment: @MarcosCramer: recommend you edit your question to state the ways it's different to the standard statement of Waring–Goldbach.

Answer (score 6):

[Brüdern (2021)](http://rivista.math.unipr.it/vols/2021-12-1/02-brudern.html) proved that every sufficiently large even integer $n$ can be written as
$$n=\sum_{k=1}^{20}x_k^{k+1},$$
where each $x_k$ is a prime number. A similar result with a few more summands was proved earlier by [Thanigasalam (1980)](https://bibliotekanauki.pl/articles/1393158), and this paper is available online for free.

Comment: Ah, I see, the paper of Prachar I cited in the comments to the question is an almost all $n$ result. I should have spent a little more time parsing the German...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access Brüdern (2021). As for Thanigasalam (1980), it does not contain a distinctness condition for the primes, so I don't know if it can be adapted to prove my conjecture that does contain the distinctness condition. I suspect that Brüdern (2021) also doesn't consider such a distinctness condition.

Comment: @MarcosCramer One can certainly modify the quoted arguments to achieve the distinctness condition for the primes. For example, in (28) of Thanigasalam's paper, one can replace the dyadic ranges $P_k\leq x\leq 2P_k$ by slightly different dyadic ranges which are pairwise disjoint, and the proof will go through. The precise value of $P_k$ in (28) is not important, all that matters is the order of magnitude of $P_k$. For example, you can replace $P_7$ by $100P_7$, say, and the conclusion will still be the same. At any rate, the point is that there is a well-established technology for such results.